# Combine Token title with url in an email

Tags: 7, forms, tokens

I send emails automatically to users. There is a link in these mails, which points to a node. But I want to use the node title as an alias for this link, so that the link is not directly displayed in the mail.

Currently I use a 'text_format' form element, where I wrote the content of the mail with the corresponding HTML code for the link:

```
<a href="[node:url]">[node:title]</a>
```

Because this just works with 'full html format', it might be possible to accomplish it in another way?

I would welcome every advise!

Thanks, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [token_replace](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7) function?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I replace the tokens I mentioned above with token_replace() and that works. But I'm not satisfied with the fact, that I have to define the content of the mail with the text format 'full html'. I thought, there might be a build-in functionality I didn't to achive my itention?

Comment: You can add another text format with the settings that you want.

Comment: Yes thats right, Drupal can be so easy ... :D
Well you mean, that there is no build-in functionality. Something like token [node:title:url] or something like that?
If it is not, I will adopt your suggestion and create a custom text format.

Comment: List of tokens. https://www.drupal.org/node/390482

Comment: Maybe the custom token module? https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom

Comment: Yes I know this list, but I couldn't find something similiar. So I guess, there is no build-in functionality and I will stay at my solution and create a new text format. thanks!